# VUE watch triggered infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm new to using VUE.Js, and i created a very simple app to try out how it works.

The problem happens immediately where when i run the app, the watch for a variable is triggered in an infinite loop. I cannot figure out why. There is a v-for loop but that is on an array that only has two elements.

Initially the SubTotal should be 0.  But as soon as the app is run, it triggers the Buy method, even though i haven't clicked the buy button and the sub total ends up being 442.37999999999965.

Thanks for any help.

Here is the jsfiddle [Beer shopping cart](https://jsfiddle.net/tbrun2014/gaaarmtv/26/)

**HTML :**

```
<div id = "growler">      
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th style='width:150px'>Beer</th>
      <th style='width:50px'>Price</th>
      <th style='width:30px'></th>
    </tr>

    <tr v-for = "beer in beers">
      <td>{{ beer.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ beer.price }}</td>
      <td>        
        <button :click="buy(beer)">buy</button>        
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>SubTotal</td>
      <td>{{subTotal}}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
  new Vue({
  el: "#growler",
  data: {
      beers: [
        {name: 'Ahool Ale', price: 2.00}, 
        {name: 'Agogwe Ale', price: 2.38}        
      ],
      shoppingCart: [], 
      subTotal: 0.00        
  }, 
  watch: {
    shoppingCart: function() {
        console.log('shopping cart watch triggered');
      this.updateSubTotal();
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    updateSubTotal: function () {
      var s=this.shoppingCart.length;
      var t=0;
      for (var i=0;i<s; i++){
        t += this.shoppingCart[i].price;
      }
      this.subTotal = t;
    }, 
    buy: function (beer) {
        console.log('beer pushed on array');
      this.shoppingCart.push(beer);
    }
  },   
  beforeCreate: function() {
    console.log('beforeCreate');
  },
  created: function() {
    console.log('created');                    
  },
  beforeMount: function() {
    console.log('beforeMount');                    
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('mounted');                    
  },
  beforeUpdate: function() {
    console.log('beforeUpdate');
  },
  updated: function() {
    console.log('updated');
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    console.log('beforeDestroy');
  },
  destroyed: function() {
    console.log('afterDestroy');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found your mistake:

```
<button :click="buy(beer)">buy</button>
```

You used `:`(`v-bind`) instead of `@`(`v-on:`) on the click handler.

When you first bind it, the function is called once and updates the `shoppingCart`. This will update the `subTotal` data, which will force a re-render of the DOM, which will trigger the `buy` function again because of the `:bind`.

Fix:

```
<button @click="buy(beer)">buy</button>  
<!-- or -->
<button v-on:click="buy(beer)">buy</button>
```

Suggested changes for your code:

Use computed properties instead of a method to update a property that represents a sum of other values:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#growler",
  data: {
    beers: [{
        name: 'Ahool Ale',
        price: 2.00
      },
      {
        name: 'Agogwe Ale',
        price: 2.38
      }
    ],
    shoppingCart: []
  },
  watch: {
    shoppingCart: function() {
      console.log('shopping cart watch triggered');
    }
  },
  computed: {
    subTotal: function() {
      return this.shoppingCart.reduce(function(total, beer) {
        return total + beer.price;
      }, 0);
    }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    buy: function(beer) {
      this.shoppingCart.push(beer);
    }
  },

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="growler">
  <button>buy</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th style='width:150px'>Beer</th>
      <th style='width:50px'>Price</th>
      <th style='width:30px'></th>
    </tr>

    <tr v-for="beer in beers">
      <td>{{ beer.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ beer.price }}</td>
      <td>
        <button @click="buy(beer)">buy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>SubTotal</td>
      <td>{{subTotal}}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You!  why use computed rather than what was there before?

Comment: Vue has this functionality out of the box. The computed property updates automatically when one of the properties it uses are also updated. It's basically like a watch, but more "automatic". It's also easier to maintain, as you don't need a specific function to change the `subTotal` property. See the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) for more examples.